# capture xml from external web service parse through nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services

I have a c# web app that has a simple task: consume an external web service, and loop through its returned xml.

I am consuming the web service like this:

```
 WSExternal.SoapHeaderCredentials objHeaderCredentials = new WSExternal.SoapHeaderCredentials();
        objHeaderCredentials.UserName = "username";
        objHeaderCredentials.Password = "password";
        WSExternal.MembershipAuthenticationService objClient = new WSExternal.MembershipAuthenticationService();
        objClient.SoapHeaderCredentialsValue = objHeaderCredentials;
```

I can call the single exposed web method like this:

```
objClient.GetMembershipUserList(false);
```

If I hit the web service through a client like SoapUI or XMLSpy, it returns xml like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">


  <soap:Body>
      <GetMembershipUserListResponse xmlns="http://namespaceofwebservice">
         <GetMembershipUserListResult>
            <UserList>
               <MembershipUserData>
                  <id>1</id>
                  <UserName>userone</UserName>
                  <PrimaryFirstName>User</PrimaryFirstName>
                  <PrimaryLastName>One</PrimaryLastName>
                  <Address>13 MAIN STREET</Address>
                  <City>ROCHESTER</City>
               </MembershipUserData>
               <MembershipUserData>
                  <id>2</id>
                  <UserName>usertwo</UserName>
                  <PrimaryFirstName>User</PrimaryFirstName>
                  <PrimaryLastName>Two</PrimaryLastName>
                  <Address>15 WEST AVE</Address>
                  <City>JERSEY CITY</City>
               </MembershipUserData>
            </UserList>
            <Page>0</Page>
         </GetMembershipUserListResult>
      </GetMembershipUserListResponse>
   </soap:Body>
```

My question is, how do I "capture" this xml from the web method, and loop through it to get the relevant data out of the nodes?

Comment: If you used "Add Service Reference", then you will receive objects, not XML. That's a Good Thing. See "[How to consume a web service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)"

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm restricted to using an old school web reference, using .net 2.0. Unless I'm mistaken, it's a bit more manual than using a service reference through the GUI. I know it's possible to in code using xml and LINQ, as I've seen it done before. I'm just spinning my wheels a bit with doing it. I am going to try and see if I can upgrade the solution, but if anyone can help with an old school approach, it would be helpful.

Comment: Also sorry about the tags in the title. It's difficult to word a question properly without saying a few keywords sometimes.

Comment: The "old school web reference" also returns objects, and not XML.

Comment: On the title, I don't mind if you _mention_ C#, my comment and edit is that it was just tacked on the beginning of an otherwise fine title